# Not enough input

Tags: c

### ***INPUT***

Integers (0 ≤ Integer  <  10^1,000,000)

### ***OUTPUT***

Find input mod 3 and input mod 11

### ***EXAMPLE***

```
main(){

        int num;//problem here i try long long not pass because it not enough.

        scanf("%d",&num);

        printf("%d ",num%3);

        printf("%d",num%11);

}
```

Comment: Have a look at fmod in math.h (man fmod).

Comment: @DavidCullen: you must be kidding! you need all the digits in base 10 to compute `num` mod `3` or `11`. Floating point is even less appropriate than `long long`

Comment: Ummm 'Integers (0 ≤ Integer < 10^1,000,000)' are you sure your range is wide enough?  :((

Comment: @Martin James The idea is certainly to consider unbounded size integer input.  This is a basic premise to many encryption algorithms where data is treated as an arbitrary length integer.  Even this example stems from grade school math: add the digits up and see if that sum divides by 3.  Further [divisibility by 1 to 20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule)

Comment: I was so tired when I read this question I didn't realize how large the range is. Can [gmp](https://gmplib.org/) handle million digit numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take advantage that mod 3 and mod 11 can easily be chained one digit at a time.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void mod3_11(void) {
  int mod3 = 0;
  int mod11 = 0;
  int ch;
  while (isdigit(ch = fgetc(stdin))) {
    int digit = ch - '0';
    mod3 = (digit + mod3)%3;
    mod11 = (digit - mod11 + 11)%11;
  }
  printf("mod 3  = %d\n", mod3);
  printf("mod 11 = %d\n", mod11);
  fflush(stdout);
  }

int main(void) {
  mod3_11();
  return 0;
}
```

---

This works as each successive digit is processed, code is taking the previous "mod" * 10

```
// math
mod_n <-- (10*mod_n + digit)%n

mod3 <-- (mod3*10 + digit) % 3
mod3 <-- (mod3*1 + mod3*3*3 + digit) % 3   
mod3 <-- (mod3 + 0 + digit) % 3    (mod3*3*3 % 3 is 0)
mod3 <-- (mod3 + digit) % 3

mod11 <-- (mod11*10 + digit) % 11
mod11 <-- (mod11*11 - mod11*1 + digit) % 11
mod11 <-- (mod11*11 - mod11 + digit + 11) % 11  (add 11 to avoid negative numbers)
mod11 <-- (-mod11 + digit + 11) % 11
```

Why add 11?  [What's the difference between “mod” and “remainder”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638659/2410359)

Answer (score 1):

"Normal types in C can usually only store up to 64 bits, so you'll have to store big numbers in an array, for example, and write mathematical operations yourself. But you shouldn't reinvent the wheel here - you could try the GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library for this purpose."

*-AndiDog*

Source:[Store and work with Big numbers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640625/store-and-work-with-big-numbers-in-c)

Comment: You can find a simpler iterative solution by reading one char at a time and performing modulo arithmetic at each step.