# Can´t add together very small floats ? C

Tags: c

I'm trying to add together 1 and 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000117549435... (2**-126), but for some reason I get number 1 printed.
I'm new to C and I'm guessing it has something to do with IEEE754? I've tried using doubles and long doubles but i haven´t got the result i need.
Not sure if it changes anything, but i need 150 decimal digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>
int main() {
    float num;
    float example;
    num = 1;
    example = 1*pow(2, -126);
    num = num + example
    printf("%.150f", num);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `150 decimal digits` is not gonna achievable with any of the default floating-point types in C in any of the current implementations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store and work with Big numbers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640625/store-and-work-with-big-numbers-in-c)

Comment: Not quiet? that one is int not float, unless i'm not seeing what you want me to see

Comment: If you need 150 digits, you're going to have to use an arbitrary-precision floating point library.  Even the biggest IEE 754 types don't get close to 150 decimal digits.  A `float` (`binary32`) can represent 6-7 decimal digits; a `double` (`binary64`) about 16-17 digits.  If you have `binary128` (might be `long double`), then you get about 34 decimal digits; if you have `binary256`, you get about 74 decimal digits (per Wikipedia on [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)).  You'd need the non-standardized (non-existent) `binary512` to get close to 150 decimal digits.

Comment: The point is that you must use a [tag:bignum] library. Did you check the famous GMP library mentioned in the other answer? *"GMP is a free library for arbitrary precision arithmetic, operating on signed integers, rational numbers, and **floating-point numbers**"*. Of course there are many other well-known libraries like Boost.Multiprecision. There are lots of duplicates already on SO

Comment: Are the values you are going to use going to be always "1+small"? You could program specifically for that, while staying with the standard types.

Comment: Are you sure you really need 150 significant digits, or do you just need an exponent range ±126?  Using floating-point numbers with that many digits implies staggering precision.  Using integers with that many digits implies cryptographic calculations — or, at least, that's probably the most common reason.  Blockchain etc counts as 'cryptographic' for this purpose.

Comment: Yeah, you should really explain what you actually need. Is it a huge amount of significant digits, or do you just need to deal with very small numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating point format can't store every number.

The numbers that it can store goes in steps. Like

```
 1.00000000000000000000000
 1.00000011920928955078125
 1.00000023841857910156250
 1.00000035762786865234375
 ...
```

So the number you are trying to store, i.e.

```
 1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000117549435..
```

can't be represented in float format. So in your case it's rounded to 1.0

Try this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

union
{
    float f;
    unsigned u;
} val;

int main() {
    assert(sizeof(float) == 4);
    assert(sizeof(unsigned) == 4);
    val.u = 0x3f800000;
    printf("0x%08x -> %.50f\n", val.u, val.f);
    ++val.u;
    printf("0x%08x -> %.50f\n", val.u, val.f);
    ++val.u;
    printf("0x%08x -> %.50f\n", val.u, val.f);
    ++val.u;
    printf("0x%08x -> %.50f\n", val.u, val.f);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x3f800000 -> 1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0x3f800001 -> 1.00000011920928955078125000000000000000000000000000
0x3f800002 -> 1.00000023841857910156250000000000000000000000000000
0x3f800003 -> 1.00000035762786865234375000000000000000000000000000
```

The above code uses a `union` of `float` and `unsigned` and an increment of the `unsigned` to get the next float.

Another way is to use `nextafterf` function to get the next representable float. Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>

union
{
    float f;
    unsigned u;
} val;

int main() {
    assert(sizeof(float) == 4);
    assert(sizeof(unsigned) == 4);
    val.f = 1*pow(2, -126);
    printf("0x%08x --> %.200f\n", val.u, val.f);
    val.f = nextafterf(val.f, 1.0);
    printf("0x%08x --> %.200f\n", val.u, val.f);
    val.f = nextafterf(val.f, 1.0);
    printf("0x%08x --> %.200f\n", val.u, val.f);
    val.f = nextafterf(val.f, 1.0);
    printf("0x%08x --> %.200f\n", val.u, val.f);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x00800000 --> 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000001175494350822287507968736537222245677818665556772087521508751706278417259454727172851562500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0x00800001 --> 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000001175494490952133940450443629595204006810278684798281709160328881985245648433835441437622648663818836212158203125000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0x00800002 --> 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000001175494631081980372932150721968162335801891812824475896811906057692074037412943710023682797327637672424316406250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0x00800003 --> 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000001175494771211826805413857814341120664793504940850670084463483233398902426392051978609742945991456508636474609375000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: How would one get said steps? Like if I input a certain float how to get the next step?

Comment: The union trick was actually a remarkable good way of illustrating this, but you should add a short explanation on what it is and why it works and link something that explains unions in more detail.

Comment: @rosewaldo There is the nextafterf function. Answer updated