# How would I add or multiply extremly large numbers e.g. 20 digit number x 5 digit number...?

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ so I don't know if there are any specific libraries that could do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does these answer your question? [Store and work with Big numbers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640625/store-and-work-with-big-numbers-in-c) and [Big numbers library in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988099/big-numbers-library-in-c)

Comment: Questions about recomendations for libraries/frameworks or similar are off-topic here on SO. Should be easy to find if you just google for it.

Comment: Terms for what you're looking for include "multiprecision" and "arbitrary precision", to guide your search.