# How to print a huge number?

Tags: c, numbers

I am trying to write a program to print Fibonacci numbers, such as

```
        0 1 1 2 3 5 8 21 ....
```

last number is sum of previous two.

I thought it is easy, but realized you have to print a huge number such as

```
   117669030460994
```

which exceeds  size of every available type of numbers in C (just checked them, far exceeds) .

So, how could I able to store and print such big number?

Comment: use a bigger printer?

Comment: For sure it doesn't exceed `unsigned long long`, which allows up to `18446744073709551615`.

Comment: Look at: https://gmplib.org/

Comment: See: [How to Code a Solution To Deal With Large Numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991175/how-to-code-a-solution-to-deal-with-large-numbers)  and [Store and work with Big numbers in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640625/store-and-work-with-big-numbers-in-c).

Comment: A 64-bit unsigned integer can store F93.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is bignums, a.k.a. [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic). There are several libraries for that, notably [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/). You'll be able to compute large Fibionacci numbers of several thousands (or even millions) of digits.

Be aware that bignum arithmetic is difficult to implement efficiently. So don't reinvent the wheel, the few simple algorithms you'll think about are less efficient than state of the art. Use an existing library (which often would use some [machine instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) like *add with carry* that speeds up such operation).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a similar program a while ago which handled `unsigned long long` integers for the Fibonacci sequence. I'm not sure how efficient it is because I used an array to store the numbers.

I also used the `%I64d` format specifier for printing the huge `64 bit` integers, because I was using windows. But I think if your using linux then `%llu` is fine.

As @M Oehm pointed out in the comments, using `uint64_t` from  is also a another way of declaring `unsigned long long`.

This is what it looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAX 100

int
main(void) {
    int i, range;

    unsigned long long array[MAX];
    /* or uint64_t from <stdint.h> */

    printf("Enter number range: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &range) != 1) {
        printf("invalid number\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    array[0] = 0;
    array[1] = 1;

    for (i = 2; i < range; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i-1] + array[i-2];
    }

    printf("Fibonacci Series is: ");
    for (i = 0; i < range; i++) {
        printf("%I64d ", array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```